# How do I Detect if a Chrome Tab is playing any audio and mute it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

*well i'm writing a extension that detects if any tab is playing audio, mutes it and then plays another audio.
however i cant find a way to detect if its playing audio and mute it. any help is greatly appreciated!*

*Im using manifest v3 btw.*

Comment: Check tab's [audible](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#type-Tab) property.

Answer (score 0):

you will see, this speaker symbol, while playing, and if it is muted then speaker cancelled symbol.

[image: "Speaker symbol"]

[image: "Mute and unmute from here"]